# on change in dropdown helper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I am using an enum to show drop down like

```
  @Html.DropDownList("MyType",EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(ImageType)),"Select My Type", new { @class = "form-control", onChange = "myFunction(this)" })
```

I want to add a onchange function to this which accept two parameter one is the current element(this) and the dropdown value

```
   onChange(this,value)
```

this should give select tag, and valu should be what I selected
what change should I ,make in my helper?

Comment: are you using `jquery`?

Comment: you can access the `value` using `this` in your function. you can implement it like this  `onChange = "myFunction(this)" `. In your function get the selected value from the dropdown.

Comment: I am console logging this, I am getting the html element. I need html elemnt as well as selected value

Comment: @vishnuprasadkv access the value using the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML Helper:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("MyType",EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(ImageType)),"Select My Type", new { @class = "form-control", onChange = "myFunction(this)" })
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
function myfunction(_this)
{
   var selectedValue = $(_this).val();
}
</script>
```

PS: you can access the element using `_this`. `val()` is going to give you the selected value.

Answer (score 1):

`@Html.DropDownList("MyType")` creates a `select` element with id, `MyType`. If you are using jQuery, you can add a change event handler like this.

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#MyType").change(function(){
            console.log($(this).val());
            console.log(this);
        });
    });
</script>
```

If you are not using jQuery, then

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        document.getElementById("MyType").addEventListener("change", function () {
            alert(this.value);
            console.log(this);
        });
    });
</script>
```

You can achieve this by `onChange` but you should follow [Unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) approach